# spring integration dsl flow variables to store & retrieve with in the flow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am looking for some flow variables where i need to store the values like orderId, customerId and other responses recieved in the flow so that i can use them in later part of flow for writing a business logic.

```
    .handle(outboundGateway("localhost:8080/order?orderId={orderId}")
                            .uriVariable("orderId", m -> m.getPayload())
                            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                            .expectedResponseType(Order.class)

    .handle(outboundGateway("localhost:8080/orderDetails?orderId={orderId}")
                            .uriVariable("orderId", m -> m.getPayload())
                            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                            .expectedResponseType(OrderDetails.class)

    .handle(outboundGateway("localhost:8080/customer?customerId={customerId}")
                            .uriVariable("customerId", m -> ((OrderDetails)m.getPayload()).getCustomerId())
                            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                            .expectedResponseType(Customer.class)

    .handle(outboundGateway("localhost:8080/customerAddress?addressId={addressId}")
                            .uriVariable("addressId", m -> ((Customer)m.getPayload()).getAdderssId)
                            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                            .expectedResponseType(CustomerAddress.class)
    .handle((p, h) -> somebusinesslogic)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such an abstraction like `state` in the flow. Well, essentially, there is no flow at runtime at all. The `IntegrationFlow` is just a logical container. More over would be better to look at Spring Integration solution as fully `stateless` (unless we talk about an `aggregator`).

Nevertheless there is a solution for you like transfer any extra required info together with the message in its headers. This way you use `.enrichHeaders()` before `.handle()` and according propagation nature of the `ServiceActivator`, the request headers are copying to the reply message and, therefore, they are available in the next flow step.

Comment: I tried with `.enrich(enricherSpec -> enricherSpec.headerFunction("orderId", m -> m.getPayload()))` and it worked, but will these headers be passed in next outbound REST request ?

Comment: That's correct. All the request headers are copying to the reply message together with the HTTP Response headers. See `AbstractMessageProducingHandler.shouldCopyRequestHeaders()`

Comment: Thanks. What is the use of `enricherSpec.propertyFunction` ?

Comment: See its JavaDocs. The `Enricher` may manipulate with `payload` as well. That's why I suggested you to use `enrichHeaders()` instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#content-enricher